# Unable to start react app using npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I have downloaded a source code and am unable to use npm start to start the react app.

when I use npmstart I get the following errors.

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/afrasiab./.npm/_logs/2023-01-13T04_36_09_195Z-debug-0.log
```

following is package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-devtools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Unable to use npm start command on my react app.

Comment: try `npm run start`

Comment: Check if you install node modules using "npm install" first and then you can run "npm run start".

Comment: what directory you are running the command ? It should be inside the projects root directory

Answer (score 1):

Correct command for starting a react application is as :

```
npm run start
```

Comment: `npm start` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't install all dependencies.  Agree with @Dipten

Use

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I also had issue while using react first time. i have solved this issue with these lines.

```
npm rm -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

2. you can add scripts in the package.json

```
,"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

3. This error also happens if you didn't open your project from the root of the project. Make sure to cd into the folder before opening it inside VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you aren't running `npm start` in the root directory. So first cd to the root directory and run `npm start`.

Also, please consider attaching a screenshot of your folder structure because it will be easy for others to help you

Comment: I Have checked this and I was in the wrong directory and could not visualize because of command line.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
,"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

with

```
  "scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
  "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
  "test": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider eject"
   },
```

then npm start

good luck